# Can we use two different prometheus.yml file for a single prometheus server

Tags: prometheus, slack, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a single prometheus server which is scraping for both prod and stage environment and I have integrated the alertmanager with my slack channel. which is working fine. I am getting alerts of both env in my slack channel.

But now I want to get alerts of prod env in one slack channel and alerts of staging env in another slack channel. How to do it. (I have only one prometheus server)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
I have used the labels in my prometheus.yml file and used the env and match in the alertmanager.yml file. with the receivers as the diffrent slack channel.

Although I am facing latency issue now, alerts are coming but quite late after 10 mins.
Anyone know how to resolve the latency issue with alertmanager and slack.